# How to get the method signatures for DShellFolderViewEvents

Tags: shell, winapi, com, atl, idispatch

I'm trying to sink `DShellFolderViewEvents` using the ATL, and the only method I've been able to successfully subscribe to is `DISPID_SELECTIONCHANGED`.  There appear to be many other events listed in the header `shdispid.h`, but I can't get them to fire. Not sure what I'm doing wrong (it might be ATL-related), but I thought perhaps I'm implementing event-handler functions with the wrong signatures (currently I'm just trying void functions with no arguments). The problem is that there doesn't appear to be documentation describing the `DShellFolderViewEvents` methods. Anyone know how to figure those out?

Comment: A quick grep of the Platform SDK reveals the method signatures in shldisp.idl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the type library for shell32.dll to get the interface declaration. I used oleview.exe which comes with Visual Studio to open the DLL. The interface looks something like this:

```
 [
  uuid(62112AA2-EBE4-11CF-A5FB-0020AFE7292D),
  helpstring("Event interface for ShellFolderView")
]
dispinterface DShellFolderViewEvents {
    properties:
    methods:
        [id(0x000000c8), helpstring("The Selection in the view changed.")]
        void SelectionChanged();
        [id(0x000000c9), helpstring("The folder has finished enumerating (flashlight is gone).")]
        void EnumDone();
        [id(0x000000ca), helpstring("A verb was invoked on an items in the view (return false to cancel).")]
        VARIANT_BOOL VerbInvoked();
        [id(0x000000cb), helpstring("the default verb (double click) was invoked on an items in the view (return false to cancel).")]
        VARIANT_BOOL DefaultVerbInvoked();
        [id(0x000000cc), helpstring("user started to drag an item (return false to cancel).")]
        VARIANT_BOOL BeginDrag();
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  There appear to be many more events defined in the header.  Do you know why those might not be present in what you found?

Comment: I have no idea. I am getting it from c:\windows\system32\ folder on my windows 10 OS.

Comment: When I looked in a header file (shldisp.h), I did not see any function definitions at all--just definitions for IDispatch. You can use the IDL file @raymondchen mentioned, or definitions imported from shell32.dll.

Comment: Oh, I mistakenly thought the DISPIDs listed around DISPID_SELECTIONCHANGED also belonged to DShellFolderViewEvents.  That's my bad.