# Detecting change in folder view mode

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, com, atl

Is there a way to hook or sink the change in an `IFolderView`'s view mode (e.g., details, icons, etc.)?

I see a `DISPID_VIEWMODECHANGED`, but I don't understand which sink that belongs to.  I don't think it belongs to `DShellFolderViewEvents`.

Also, I don't believe that `DWebBrowserEvents2`'s `DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE` fires when the view mode changes.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: you can't fundamentally change the question or tags once the question is asked. You can just ask another question and link to it.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it using `SINK_ENTRY_INFO`.  Thanks again for your answer.  I'll be accepting it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed `DISPID_VIEWMODECHANGED` for `DShellFolderViewEvents`, but it's quite complex to get it.

Here is a Console App sample code that monitors all view mode changes for all currently open Explorer views. So to test it you must:

1. open some Explorer view(s);
2. run the program. When you change any of the opened folder view mode, you should see the event printed.

Some reference links:

[Receiving a notification any time the selection changes in an Explorer window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140922-00/?p=44013)

[Dispatch interfaces as connection point interfaces](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130612-00/?p=4103)

```
int main()
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  {
    CComPtr<IShellWindows> windows;
    windows.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows);

    long count = 0;
    windows->get_Count(&count);

    // array to remember one sink for one view
    CAtlArray<CComPtr<CShellFolderViewEventsSink>> sinks;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      // get window #i
      CComPtr<IDispatch> disp;
      windows->Item(CComVariant(i), &disp);
      if (disp)
      {
        // get top level browser
        CComPtr<IShellBrowser> browser;
        CComQIPtr<IServiceProvider>(disp)->QueryService(SID_STopLevelBrowser, IID_PPV_ARGS(&browser));
        if (browser)
        {
          // get shell view
          CComPtr<IShellView> view;
          browser->QueryActiveShellView(&view);
          if (view)
          {
            // get the ShellViewFolder (scripting) object
            CComPtr<IDispatch> viewDisp;
            view->GetItemObject(SVGIO_BACKGROUND, IID_PPV_ARGS(&viewDisp));
            if (viewDisp)
            {
              CComPtr<IShellFolderViewDual> fview;
              viewDisp->QueryInterface(&fview);
              if (fview)
              {
                CComPtr<CShellFolderViewEventsSink> sink;
                sink.Attach(new CShellFolderViewEventsSink());
                sinks.Add(sink);
                sink->Connect(fview);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // wait for user input (and pump messages)
    MessageBox(nullptr, L"Click to stop listening", L"View Events", MB_OK);
    for (int i = 0; i < sinks.GetCount(); i++)
    {
      sinks.GetAt(i)->Disconnect();
    }
  }
  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}

// class that checks for DISPID_VIEWMODECHANGED
class CShellFolderViewEventsSink : public CDispInterfaceBase<DShellFolderViewEvents>
{
public:
  CShellFolderViewEventsSink() { }
  HRESULT Invoke( DISPID dispid, DISPPARAMS* pdispparams, VARIANT* pvarResult)
  {
    switch (dispid)
    {
    case DISPID_VIEWMODECHANGED:
      printf("DISPID_VIEWMODECHANGED called\n");
      break;
    }
    return S_OK;
  }
};

// support class to hook IDispatch events
template<typename DispInterface>
class CDispInterfaceBase : public DispInterface
{
  LONG m_cRef;
  CComPtr<IConnectionPoint> m_spcp;
  DWORD m_dwCookie;

public:
  CDispInterfaceBase() : m_cRef(1), m_dwCookie(0) { }

  // IDispatch
  IFACEMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
  {
    *ppv = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
    if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_IDispatch || riid == __uuidof(DispInterface))
    {
      *ppv = static_cast<DispInterface*>(static_cast<IDispatch*>(this));
      AddRef();
      hr = S_OK;
    }
    return hr;
  }

  IFACEMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef() { return InterlockedIncrement(&m_cRef); }
  IFACEMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release() { LONG cRef = InterlockedDecrement(&m_cRef); if (!cRef) delete this; return cRef; }

  // IDispatch
  IFACEMETHODIMP GetTypeInfoCount(UINT* pctinfo) { *pctinfo = 0; return E_NOTIMPL; }
  IFACEMETHODIMP GetTypeInfo(UINT iTInfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo** ppTInfo) { *ppTInfo = nullptr; return E_NOTIMPL; }
  IFACEMETHODIMP GetIDsOfNames(REFIID, LPOLESTR* rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID* rgDispId) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
  IFACEMETHODIMP Invoke(DISPID dispid, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pdispparams, VARIANT* pvarResult, EXCEPINFO* pexcepinfo, UINT* puArgErr)
  {
    if (pvarResult) VariantInit(pvarResult);
    return Invoke(dispid, pdispparams, pvarResult);
  }

  virtual HRESULT Invoke(DISPID dispid, DISPPARAMS* pdispparams, VARIANT* pvarResult) = 0;

public:
  HRESULT Connect(IUnknown* punk)
  {
    CComPtr<IConnectionPointContainer> spcpc;
    HRESULT  hr = punk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spcpc));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) hr = spcpc->FindConnectionPoint(__uuidof(DispInterface), &m_spcp);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) hr = m_spcp->Advise(this, &m_dwCookie);
    return hr;
  }

  void Disconnect()
  {
    if (m_dwCookie)
    {
      m_spcp->Unadvise(m_dwCookie);
      m_spcp.Release();
      m_dwCookie = 0;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure it's part of DShellFolderViewEvents?  The interface definition indicates otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59565687/13366655

Comment: @loop123123 - they're listed in shdispid.h as "events for the shell folder view" and guess what, it works. A dispinterface is just an IDispatch implementation + a list of dispids + possible arguments. The DShellFolderViewEvents declaration in the idl is almost useless. What's important is the dispids list, and even if there are arguments (in pdispparams), we don't need/use them. It's probably shldisp.idl (and therefore the embedded .tlb in shell32.dll) that's not up to date.

Comment: So then is it not possible to sink it using the ATL sink map? Or is it possible to update the definition manually?

Comment: Suggestion: Mark all class members as `noexcept`. That provides a safeguard against implementations attempting to pass exceptions across the ABI.

Comment: @loop123123 - Your question is not on ATL, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. ATL sink uses the dispid too (what else since that's all there is?). Maybe the wizards don't work, yes since the idl and tlb are missing lots of information.

Comment: @IInspectable - Sure. For that part, I basically borrowed Raymond Chen's pre-chewed classes.